# Assigning factor levels with ifelse and alternatives

Tags: r

I have multiple dataframes, which i which to merge and melt. After melting, i want to add a identifier to the long dataframe, based on the original dataframe a row belongs to.

```
library(reshape2)
df1 <- data.frame(User=factor(LETTERS[24:26]), A=c(1,2,3), B=c(1,2,3))
df2 <- data.frame(User=factor(LETTERS[23:25]), C=c(1,2,3), D=c(1,2,3))

df.comb <- merge(df1, df2, by="User", all=T)
df.m <- melt(df.comb, id.vars="User")
```

and here i assign the factor `cat` based on the appearance of the variables (A,B,C,D) in `df.m$variables` in the column names of df1 and df2.

```
df.m$cat <- ifelse(df.m$variable %in% names(df1) , "df1",
                   ifelse(df.m$variable %in% names(df2),  "df2", "df1"))
```

Unfortunately i have many more dataframes (nine in total); so ifelse becomes very tedious and complex (if possible; i havent tried).

```
df3 <- data.frame(User=factor(LETTERS[22:24]), E=c(1,2,3), F=c(1,2,3))

df.comb <- merge(merge(df1, df2, by="User", all=T), df3, by="User", all=T)
df.m <- melt(df.comb, id.vars="User")
```

What is the best way to assign `df.m$cat` based on the appearances of `df.m$variable` in the column names of the dataframes? The column names of all my dataframes are unique.

Comment: the `case_when` statement from `dplyr` can help you out.

Comment: this worked: df.m$cat  <- as.factor(case_when(
            df.m$variable %in% names(df1)~ "df1",
            df.m$variable %in% names(df2)~ "df2",
            df.m$variable %in% names(df3) ~ "df3")). Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `case_when` from `dplyr`. The `TRUE` is the else part if none of the other options work.

```
library(dplyr)
df.m$cat <- as.factor(case_when(df.m$variable %in% names(df1) ~ "df1", 
                                df.m$variable %in% names(df2) ~ "df2", 
                                df.m$variable %in% names(df3) ~ "df3",
                                TRUE ~ "No df"))
```